# What is the optimal model for a user database in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

I just started learning DRF and I was wondering what's the best approach to build the model for users. I want to serve the data from my rest API to mobile so getting out specific fields out of the API is crucial. Is it possible to nest in the same model and say retrieve the "email" for data set with id 1?

serializers.py

```
from .models import UserDatabase
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserDatabaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializing the user database with our fields
    Adding them directly to the database
    """

    class Meta:
        model = UserDatabase
        fields = ("id","email","first_name","last_name","passw")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class UserDatabase(models.Model):
    """
    """
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=320)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    passw = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

**EDIT** What I meant to say is, how should my models and serializers look in order to be able to query a specific field like "email" after I find a user by querying his "id".

Comment: This question is not clear: "Is it possible to nest in the same model and say retrieve the "email" for data set with id 1?". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @lucasnadalutti Yes I can see now it's very broad. What I meant to say was what kind of model practice should I use for a basic User database with the models listen in my models.py . How's should my serializer relations look like in order for my api endpoints to be able to query a specific field like "email" from say the first user.